# Confused by an interaction of pandas and numpy when reading a matrix from a file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a space-separated text file containing a matrix (with the matrix size in the header). I need to remove some lines and columns from it and then save it in the exact same format (well, except for the header, that's easy to fix later). Here's the external code the text file **must** work with:

```
from pandas import read_table, DataFrame
path = os.path.join(root+'sys_full_long.dat')
     # The first line should contain the length.
with open(path, 'r') as text:
    length = int(text.readline())
        # Note that this function does not require to skiprows, as it
        # understands the convention of writing the length in the first
        # line
matrix = read_table(path).to_numpy().reshape((length, length))
print(matrix.shape)
```

It works just fine with the initial file. I edit the matrix and save the result as (fixing the header afterwards)

```
cmatrix = DataFrame(croptrix)
cmatrix.to_csv(root+'sys_crop_long.dat',sep=' ',index=False)
```

However, the new file no longer behaves as expected when I try to recover the matrix from it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-fff8cf845e77> in <module>
      7         # understands the convention of writing the length in the first
      8         # line
----> 9 ccmatrix = read_table(cpath).to_numpy().reshape((clength, clength))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 751 into shape (751,751)
```

Basically what happens is the result of read_table(cpath).to_numpy() is now a [clength,1] size array of *strings* (i.e. each matrix row is treated as one element) instead of a [clength*clength,1] size array of numbers. I'm no expert in pandas and file formatting, so I can't find a structural difference between the old file and the new one.

Comment: We need to see file samples to be sure, but often this problem arises when the dataframe has lists or arrays as cell values.  A frame is 2d, as is a csv.  But these 'nested' lists add a 3rd dimension.  All it can do is write the string formatted version of the array to the file, which will also be loaded as a string.  Previous SO have suggested ways of converting those strings.  But first lets make sure you/we know what's in those files.

Comment: `pandas` doesn't display strings with quotes, so it can be hard to see whether a cell contains an array or list, or a string that just looks lilke one.  The `to_numpy` hasn't converted anything.  If it has strings, so does the dataframe.

Comment: @hpaulj The initial file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K0_pX9C6tMfZtzipUEDUwqRKdr-anPDL/view?usp=drivesdk, the problematic one is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0NgwOEmfVu-fxjhqnFk7U80f0ZrM7ri/view?usp=drivesdk (if it's comma separated right now, then it's the wrong version and I'll fix that when I get back, but the issue arises both using space and comma separators)

Comment: A csv has only one level of separator.  Space separated strings are left as is when loaded.

Comment: I'm not going to download your files!